# SQL - How to join tables with dates to get overall view of ALL dates

Tags: sql, join

Using a bespoke ERP system with T & A built in.
Table 1 has dates with holidays types i.e. bank holidays, user booked holidays - and a user id.

Table 2 has all the clockings for that user id - so, clock in time and date, clock out time and date, user id

Is there a way to show all of the dates in a week, for example by amalgamating the two tables.

E.g. table 1 has a bank holiday on monday, users have clocked tue, wed, thu - or a user hasn't clocked at all because the holiday table has them off all week?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

A **Left Join** or **Right Join** would do the trick.

```
SELECT T1.data1, T2.data2 FROM table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS T2
ON foreignKey1 = primnaryKey2
```

This will join the two tables including the null values from the "left" table. Right joins do the same with the right one. All depends on which table references the other in a Foreign Key. Note that in this example T1 is left and T2 is right.

Comment: Thanks for this.
I did play about with joins first and was getting nowhere. When i try this, all i get is all the lines that match rather than the ones that don't.
I created a calendar table with all the dates in for the year to try and come at it from a different angle in the hope that I can look at the calendar file first for my date range, then check out the other two tables to see if there's anything in there for that day.
Just not sure if what I want to do is possible.